# Job action string too long

Tags: oracle, action, jobs

I'm trying to create a job that will sync two databases in the midnight. There are 10 tables that need to be synced. And it's a very long PL SQL script. When I set this script to JOB ACTION and try to create the job I get "string value too long for attribute job action". What do you suggest I do? Should I seperate the scipt into 10? Isn't there a way to make the job run the code as a script. If I do it manualy all 10 anonymous blocks get executed one after another. I need something that will kind of press F5 for me in the midnight.

Comment: move your code to a procedure?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a DBMS_Scheduler chain, in which each action is a separate step and they can be executed at the same time.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm

Comment: +1, although I think the documentation is less than clear here. Try this link too: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#BAJHFHCD